# Changing axis with ts.plot - R

Tags: r, time-series

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJvMk.png][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJvMk.png)

So, after hours and days working to my time serie, I have finally managed to get one which is not so bad. I owe this a lot to the community.

However, I am having trouble at the end, to redefine the x and y axis, and change the interval. Indeed, I wish I could have my X axis as a date format, while, currently, it is just a suite of number (cf picture attached). Also, I would like to change the scale of the y axis.

The thing is that I tried to put `axes = F` in my `ts.plot` function, but it does not take that parameter into account. It works for most of the plot functions, but not this one, and, unfortunately, I do not know how I can do what I did with another ts plot function...

Here an abstract of my datas :

```
month         AveragePrice pct.chg

1 sep 2016             3.17    0    
2 oct 2016             0.792  -0.750
3 nov 2016             0.225  -0.715
4 déc 2016             0.179  -0.204
5 jan 2017             0.445   1.48 
6 fév 2017             3.36    6.55
```

and here the infos of the df :

```
> dput(head(MonthlyAveragePricesHAIRPEPE, 10))

structure(list(month = structure(c(2016.66666666667, 2016.75, 
2016.83333333333, 2016.91666666667, 2017, 2017.08333333333, 2017.16666666667, 
2017.25, 2017.33333333333, 2017.41666666667), class = "yearmon"), 
    AveragePrice = c(3.16968709677419, 0.791904347826087, 0.225412279295455, 
    0.179445766423358, 0.444554531722054, 3.35761658783784, 5.6894554715794, 
    16.6639257580906, 53.1994216287425, 66.4208618873239), pct.chg = c(0, 
    -0.750163242096669, -0.71535415872605, -0.203921955874672, 
    1.4773754242451, 6.55276652974736, 0.694492305103592, 1.9289139956068, 
    2.19249031716991, 0.24852601501664)), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is my code :

```
fit <- arima(log(MonthlyAveragePricesHAIRPEPE$AveragePrice), order=c(1,0,0),seasonal = list(order = c(1, 0, 1), period = 1))
pred <- predict(fit, n.ahead = 18)
ts.plot(as.ts(MonthlyAveragePricesHAIRPEPE$AveragePrice),2.73^pred$pred, log = "y", lty = c(1,3), xlab = "Date", ylab="Average Price Per Unit")
```

So, to resume, I am looking for a way to either change directly the interval and the measurement of the axis, or at least a way to not display these... Many thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

tt <- as.ts(read.zoo(MonthlyAveragePricesHAIRPEPE[1:2]))
fit <- arima(log(tt), order = c(1, 0, 0),seasonal = list(order = c(1, 0, 1), period = 1))
pred <- predict(fit, n.ahead = 18)
z <- as.zoo(cbind(tt, 2.73^pred$pred))
plot(z, screen = 1)
```

[image: screenshot]

or replace last line with:

```
library(ggplot2)
autoplot(z, facet = NULL, na.rm = TRUE) + scale_x_yearmon()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your return ! The first code gives a nonsense result, and for the second one, I get something better but I get the following error : "Removed 35 rows containing missing values (geom_path). " and I do indeed have missing values in the graph...

Comment: Also, do you know how I can rename "2.73^pred$pred" on the graph ?

Comment: If what you mean by "nonsense result" that it gives a two panel result and you want them in one panel I have changed it by adding screen=1 to give a single panel.  Regarding the ggplot2 warnings they do not affect the result.

Comment: Also you can change the column names of z using `names(z) <- c("series1", "series2")` and that will change the labels on the legend.

Comment: Wow, MANY MANY thanks ! ! ! That will do it mostly, I should pass my class thanks to this lol. Just, is there a solution for the error "Removed 35 rows containing missing values (geom_path). " ? If not, no worries, you really helped me a lot !

Comment: Gaddem, you are really impressive, works perfectly. Just, would you have any idea of how to do that all while keeping the color demarcation between forecast and observed datas ? 

Also, and I am sorry to ask something again, how do I do If I want to do this with the pct.change column  ? I have a problem when I arrive at 

fit <- arima(log(passeddatas), order = c(1, 0, 0),seasonal = list(order = c(1, 0, 1), period = 1))". it says "Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  no case has anything else than missing values (NA)"